# How to create a pdf with a colored border

Tags: php, fpdf

I need to create a pdf using the fpdf class with a colored border that is 15mm thick on the top, right and left and 32mm thick at the bottom (border color is orange for the sake of argument) which leaves a white background in the middle for the text content.

How can I best achieve this please ?

Comment: Maybe it's too late, but if anyone still needs colorized border, *SetDrawColor* function can help: http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/setdrawcolor.htm

Comment: Would have been nice to be able to set that for ```CellFormat```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use FDPF. Use DomPDF - it accepts HTML as input, where you can easily do what you're describing, and produces PDF from it.

Comment: Not very helpful, the question is about fpdf not about what can replace it